# Approximation concerning gravitational waves from binary neutron star

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, neutron-stars, binary-stars, post-newtonian

I'm interested in studying two neutron stars orbiting each other and producing gravitational waves. In textbooks the calculation for the power of the radiation is done by considering the neutron stars as points in space. **Is this an approximation?** If I were to consider them as 3-dimensional objects (for example, numerically using discrete sampling), would I get different value for power or does the spherical shape make it so that this approach would give the same answer as just considering the neutron stars as points?

Edit:
I'll try to clarify the problem. When calculating the energy-momentum tensor $T$ for the system of two neutron stars orbiting in a circular orbit, usually the calculation is made simpler by shrinking all of the mass of the neutron star into it's center of mass. My question is, would the result for power change if I didn't do this and instead calculated the energy-momentum tensor by considering the neutron star as it is. Hope this clarifies the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The gravitational waves is an effect produced by small variations on the metric that describes the space-time outside of the star ($T_{\mu \nu} = 0$). So, yes, assuming a star is a point in space is simplifiying, but why would you want it to be a sphere, that doesn't give you any information at all. Remeber, the perturbations OUTSIDE the body are the ones that gives you the solution of gravitational waves.

Comment: Yes, of course I'm interested in perturbations outside the stars, but the waves are dependent on the source. I'm asking if this simplifying step is changing the source such that the waves change.

Comment: For example, considering a single spinning spherical neutron star as the source, making the neutron star into a point doesn't change the results, there is no gravitational waves produced. I'm asking if in my given case this makes difference.

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric).

Comment: The Kerr metric is for black holes, but you could obtain solutions for neutron stars that behave more or less the same as the black hole case. Basically the effect that produces the rotation of this object is that space-time is draged with the body itself, in a similar way that of a river flow, or a tornado.

Comment: Textbooks usually use the quadrupole formula for gravitational radiation. This in itself is an approximation, even for point masses. But (I think) it is a *further* approximation to calculate the mass quadrupole moment as if the neutron stars are points. On the other hand, is the density profile of neutron stars even understood?

Comment: @Ghoster This answers my guestion, thanks! You are right, there are many other approximations too. I'm just thinking of doing my bachelors thesis on this topic of binary neutron star and I thought that taking away even one approximation and seeing what it does is enough for bachelors level

Answer (score 2):

The calculations you a referring to are usually done as part of a post-Newtonian expansion of binary dynamics. These calculations are greatly simplified by treating the components of the binary as (spinning*) point particles. This is known to be an approximation, however the level of the approximation is well under control. Non-point particle corrections are known to enter the dynamics at the 5th post-Newtonian order, a result known as the effacement principle.

*Effects due to spin enter much earlier in the calculation, but can be included as part of the point particle approximation.